# Polish encoding in Microsoft Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, encoding, bulk

I have a problem with characters encoding in my ms sql server (version Enterprise 2014). I create bulk files via c# program, bulk are encoded in UTF-8 with polish characters, but when I insert bulk into my database instead of strings with polish characters I have strings with default ASCII characters.

Here is my create table declaration:

```
create table Klient
(
    imie varchar(20),
    nazwisko varchar(40),
    id int identity(1,1),
    primary key (id),
)
```

Here is a part of my bulk file:

```
...
Sylwiusz|Okyne|1
Adolf|Osientowicz|2
Jagoda|Chołyś|3
Wanda|Peryhasza|4
Milena|Czybieniak|5
Katarzyna|Czarnopyś|6
Witomir|Chałubowicz|7
Rut|Garuz|8
Rut|Sciolny|9
Klementyna|Leszer|10
Lucjusz|Boralciewicz|11
...
```

Here is a script which push bulk to the database:

```
BULK INSERT Klient FROM 'src' WITH (KEEPIDENTITY, FIELDTERMINATOR='|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

Here is my database properties:
[image]

Here is properties of column which has string with polish characters:
[image]

And here is what it looks into my database:

[image]

I also try using nvarchar instead of varchar but it didn't help for me. Maybe I should use another collation? But I don't have idea which one because there is about 30-40 polish collations.. So if someone could help me I will be very grateful!

## EDIT

Regarding to @Giorgios answer adding codepage="65001" didn't help for me because sql server returns info that he isn't support it. I also find info that sql server never support codepage 65001, but it's a [info](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/370419) from 2009, but I don't know if it's actual with sql server 2014..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to my edit, and what @Roger F. Wolf said. Ms sql doesn't support UTF-8. And to deal with this I change method of generating data to the database. In my c# program to create bulk file instead of using:

```
using (var sr = new StreamWriter(String.Format("{0}.bulk", this.clientPath))
```

I use this:

```
using (var sr = new StreamWriter(File.Open(String.Format("{0}.bulk", this.clientPath), FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.Unicode)
```

And for me it works fine!
Here is what I get:

My bulk file:

[image]

and select from my database:

[image]

and also communique from sql:

[image]

## Edit

Solution to this sql communique, is what @Roger said (adding DATAFILETYPE to sql script with bulk insert)

```
BULK INSERT Klient FROM 'src' WITH (KEEPIDENTITY, FIELDTERMINATOR='|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', DATAFILETYPE='widechar');
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You're welcome :) Regarding that last nuisance, it is probably worth changing your load statement slightly: `BULK INSERT Klient FROM 'src' WITH (KEEPIDENTITY, FIELDTERMINATOR='|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', datafiletype='widechar');` - should be safer that way.

Comment: @Roger I change statement and communique dissapear :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support UTF-8 (and probably never will). In the help article for latest version `bulk insert`, it is stated absolutely clear:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms188365.aspx

Same is true for `bcp.exe`, of course.

It might help to reencode your file into UTF-16, which is backward compatible with UCS-2 (which SQL Server actually uses). As an option, you may try to create a SSIS package where first step will be a conversion and second is  an actual bulk insert.

Comment: upvote for convice me to do what I want before, and it works!